# Get child compoent state inside ErrorBoundary on componentDidCatch React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I am trying to implement `ErrorBoundary` by following the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) and so far been successful.

I have used the same approach mentioned in the docs

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyWidget />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

What I can not accomplish is to get the state of the child component `MyWidget` inside the `ErrorBoundary` in the `componentDidCatch` function of `ErrorBoundary`. I want to send the child component state along with the error to the server so that it would be easier to debug.

What I've tried so far is to use `refs` like

```
<ErrorBoundary childrenRef={this.refs["myWidget"]}>
   <MyWidget ref="myWidget"/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

And then in my child component, I have created a function `getState` that simply returns own state, then inside the `ErrorBoundary` I am getting the state of the child component using the provided `ref` like

```
render() {
    if (this.props.childrenRef) {
      console.log(this.props.childrenRef.decoratedRef.current.getState());
    }
    if (this.state.errorInfo) {
      // Error path
      console.log(this.state.errorInfo);
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
          <details style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
            {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
            <br />
            {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
          </details>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // Normally, just render children
    return this.props.children;
  }
```

which does the job and returns the state of the child component, but when I try to use the same code of getting state using refs inside `componentDidCatch` then this `this.props.childrenRef.decoratedRef.current` results in `null`, maybe because the child component had an error and is unmounted so `current` becomes `null` which previously had the reference to the child component itself.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm trying to do exactly this for debugging, but have not gotten around the "null" problem in componentDidCatch.

Comment: No, I couldn't, the only hack I could think of is to lift the state up on each child state update and save it inside the parent component.

Comment: Thanks. That has been my approach as well, which is too bad, because it means lifting the state up to the ErrorBoundary, which just seems a little off to me. Great question out here - wish I had an answer!